# Slicing a list of str in Python

Tags: python, slice

I can't get the slicing to work properly. I have a list of strings looking like this:

```
['subdomain', 'name', 'url']
['https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1', 'Cümen-Cümen Empanadas Palermo', 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cumen-cumen-empanadas-palermo-menu']
['https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1', 'Cümen-Cümen Empanadas - Barrio Norte', 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cumen-cumen-empanadas-barrio-norte-menu']
```

What I need is to save the 'url' in a new list to further work on it.

This is what I'm trying

```
for row[3:3] in reader:
   menus = []
   menus.append[row]
```

But this is what I get when I print():

```
['https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=5', 'La Pergola - Recoleta', 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-pergola-recoleta-menu']
```

Which is the last part of the list. 
What I need is:

```
menus = ['https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cumen-cumen-empanadas-palermo-menu', 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cumen-cumen-empanadas-barrio-norte-menu']
```

---

I've added the rest of the code. The issue is that it's not a list of str as I thought but type() = '_csv.reader'

Here is the entire code:

```
urls = ["https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery",]

with open("output1.csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['subdomain', 'name', 'url'])

    for url in urls:
        base = url+ "?bt=RESTAURANT&page="
        page = 1
        restaurants = []

        while True:
            soup = bs(requests.get(base + str(page)).text, "html.parser")

        sections = soup.find_all("section", attrs={"class": "restaurantData"})

        if not sections: break

        for section in sections:
            for elem in section.find_all("a", href=True, attrs={"class": "arrivalName"}):
                restaurants.append({"name": elem.text, "url": elem["href"],})
                writer.writerow([base+str(page),elem.text,elem["href"]])
        page += 1    

#reading
file = open("output1.csv", 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: If you want only the url, then you don't want a _slice_ at all; you just want a single item.  Use `row[2]`.

Comment: It should be `for row in reader:`

Comment: @chepner apparently my brain isn;t working today. You are correct, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of lists (ie an extra `[]` around your lists) and not 3 isolated lists as your question implies, you can loop through your lists of lists and take the `url` element from each (element 2) to append to a new list.

```
reader = csvreader or whatever you do to define it
menu = []    
for n, i in enumerate(reader): 
    if(n != 0):
        print(i[2])
        menu.append(i[2])
```

I have altered the code to work with the csvreader object.  Instead of my old way to ignore the first element we will use `enumerate` a fantastic function that counts which element of the reader we are in as `n`.  So as long as `n` is not zero we will continue like before.

Comment: He probably wants the slice `abc[1:]`, to skip over the heading row.

Comment: Good call, added

Comment: I've added the entire code. Problem is type = ._csv.reader

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand csv.reader correctly it should work the same as a list for my bit of code.  If instead of `abc` you use: `for i in reader[1:]:` I think it should work.  If not let me know the error message.

Comment: Ok, that's the `[1:]` that's not allowed so the shortcut for ignoring the first line won't work this way.  I'll edit the code to something that will make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want this:

```
menus = []
for row in reader:
    menus.append(row[2])
```

I don't understand what you're trying to do by making `row[3:3]` the iterated variable of a `for` loop.  I think you want to iterate over simple rows and then do something with each row inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue does not lie in the slicing (although you could also directly index with [2]). However, you reinitialize menus in the loop. So for every run of the loop, you overwrite what was previously there.
This should fix it:

```
menus = []
for row in reader:
   menus.append[row[2]]
```

## List comprehension

A cleaner (and more pythonic) approach would be to use a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
menus = [row[2] for row in reader]
```

Comment: I get: `NameError: name 'row' is not defined` for your first code snippet.

Comment: @quamrana Ah, didn't actually run the code. This should have fixed it.

Comment: Hmm, `row[3:3]` would be empty given the data from the OP.

Comment: That's the issue I was getting and going crazy over! hahah. Problem is because it's not a list of str but a '_csv.reader' type. I've added the entire code